# Unity Standalone App: Resolution Scaling Issue (OSX)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have developed a Mac-OSX standalone app in Unity3D (Scale with Resolution: 1920x1080). Most of the time I present the app on my laptop, connected to an external screen, which works pretty well.

But when I'm on the road and use the app on my laptop screen (1440x900), the UI's are all over the place...

I know, BUT is there a way to run the app in a 16:9 ratio (with black bars on the top and bottom), the same as I can do it in the Unity3D editor?

I don't want to go back and re-scale everything to a lower resolution, as this would be a crazy job :(

Is there any solution without re-doing it?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, but sadly this didn't work for me. The problem is my Reference Resolution in the Canvas Scaler is already set to 1920x1080. To fix this, I have to lower the reference, but this means re-doing all the UI's.

However, I found a workaround, which is strange but working. I have set the Default Screen Resolution in Unity to 1920x1080 as in the image/link below.

Now the strange part :)
1. Start the app with the option key on an HD screen and set the resolution to 1920x1080.
2. Save and Quit
3. Now the app is scaled down to 16:9 and keeps everything in place.

This works as long as you don't start this app or any other Unity build, with the option key on a lower resolution screen. In this case it will scale everything back again. You can redo the steps 1-3 and it will work again.

Not sure if there is another way to do this, but at least I have kind of a solution.

[Default Screen Resolution in Unity to 1920x1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91eli.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should check; 'Resolution and Presentation' under 'Player Settings', and canvas scalers. I have being in a situation similar to yours, I had built an iOS application meant for the vertical orientation, but also wanted to test it on macOS, the application launched correctly in fullscreen mode looking like this (The top status bar was intentionally brought down to show the aspect ratio):

[image]

Instead of using black bars on the sides, it seems like that Unity simply used the colour of the canvas of the current scene to fill in the gaps. This was my settings to get this result:

[image]

Only the 16:10 ratio (MacBook Pro) was checked, but the application functions in the iPhone's vertical ratio, I did not have to manually rescale the canvas,I simply switched the build platform, this was allowed by the canvas scalers I have added onto every canvas with the following setting (UI Scale mode: Scale with screen size | Screen match mode: expand), this would allow the canvas to expand automatically and scale to any aspect ratio, without messing up the UI:

[image]

Hope this Helps!